# ES6 - Looping through keys in object and then assigning to new object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

On page load I am calling a metadata API which returns an object with the metadata type as the key name and an array of metadata objects as the value like so:

[image]

The metadata objects need to be simplified and altered to play nicely with my React input components (each object will be a separate checkbox or radio button with a value and label). I basically need to return the same format but with value and label keys instead of id, display_on, name etc. I am doing the following in my container component to alter the data ready for being passed via props to my form components. The issue is that `metadataFormattedForInput` always return an empty object.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const metadataFormattedForInput = {};
  Object.keys(state.metadata).forEach((key) => {
    const metadataOptions = [];
    state.metadata[key].map(option => (
      metadataOptions.push({ value: option.id, label: option.name })
    ));
    return (
      Object.assign({}, metadataFormattedForInput, {
        [key]: metadataOptions,
      })
    );
  });

  return {
    metadataOptions: metadataFormattedForInput,
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `metadata` object..?

Comment: Returning to a `forEach` loop really doesn't do anything ?

Comment: as well as returning from a forEach, why use `state.metadata[key].map` and discard the resulting array? use `const metadataOptions = state.metadata[key].map(option => ({ value: option.id, label: option.name });`

Comment: `metadataFormattedForInput` is not modified by that call of `Object.assign`. In fact that `Object.assign` is completely useless as neither the first argument, nor the return value is retained.

Comment: Removing the empty {} from the Object.assign function was actually all that was needed, however the accepted answer is a nicer way of writing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is the way you're using `Object.assign` (you're adding the properties to an empty object that you just discard afterwards because it's returned in a `forEach` call). However, `Object.assign` is unnecessary:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const metadataFormattedForInput = {};

  Object.keys(state.metadata).forEach(key => {
    metadataFormattedForInput[key] = state.metadata[key].map(option =>
      ({ value: option.id, label: option.name })
    );
  });

  return {
    metadataOptions: metadataFormattedForInput,
  };
}

const metadata = {
  phaseofthegame: [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}],
  theme: [{id: 2, name: 'bar'}]
};

console.log(
  mapStateToProps({ metadata }).metadataOptions
);
```

If you want to keep using `Object.assign`, then you can combine it with `Array.reduce`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const renameProps = (acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, {
    [key]: state.metadata[key].map(option =>
      ({ value: option.id, label: option.name })
    )
  });

  const metadataOptions =
    Object.keys(state.metadata).reduce(renameProps, {});

  return { metadataOptions };
}
```

Comment: ES6 lets you shorthand property names in object literals if the value is the same, if you choose `metadataOptions` instead of `metadataFormattedForInput ` as the name, you can shorthand `{metadataOptions}` and `{metadata}`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the issue with your code:

- You are using `forEach` in the wrong way, `forEach` don't return any value. In case you want to return some value, use `map`.
- Also, you are using `map` and using it like `forEach` i.e. you are not utilizing the returned value

  ```
  function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    let metadataFormattedForInput = Object.keys(state.metadata).reduce((metadataFormattedForInput, key) => {
    let metadataOptions = state.metadata[key].map(option =>
      ({ value: option.id, label: option.name })
    );
      metadataFormattedForInput[key] = metadataOptions;
      return metadataFormattedForInput;
    },{});

    return {
      metadataOptions: metadataFormattedForInput,
    };
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, and some other issues:

- Returning a value in a `forEach` callback has no effect
- On the other hand, a `map` callback *should* have a returned value
- `Object.assign` does not mutate the second argument, so `metadataFormattedForInput` is not modified at all

Here is a functional way to do this, moving the `Object.assign` call outside the `map` and building the output with the spread syntax:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        metadataOptions: Object.assign(...Object.keys(state.metadata).map(key => (
            { [key]: state.metadata[key].map(option => (
                    { value: option.id, label: option.name }
                ))
            }
        )))
    };
}


var state = {
    metadata: {
        phaseofthegame: [
            { id: 123, display_on: ['a', 'b'], name: 'Attacking' },
            { id: 456, display_on: ['c', 'd'], name: 'Transition to Attack' },
        ],
        theme: [
            { id: 789, display_on: ['e', 'f'], name: 'Rondo' },
            { id: 101, display_on: ['g', 'h'], name: 'Defending Individually' },
        ]
    }
};

state = mapStateToProps(state);

console.log(JSON.stringify(state, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```